# How can I get my anchor link to scroll smoothly back up top like it does when it goes down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get my page to scroll back to my top anchor smoothly like it does when I go down to my bottom anchor. However instead of scrolling smoothly, it jumps without any animation.

Could someone assist me in pointing out what I can do to make it scroll smoothly both ways?

JavaScript

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rohithdm/atg8xcyd/)

Answer (score 2):

The ID of the `<a href="#myAnchor" name="topAnchor" id="anchor1">`  is wrong, set it to `id="topAnchor"` and it will work nicely.

Comment: @RP12 glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you target the top anchor by id instead of by name, it will scroll smoothly.  (It had an ID of `anchor1`.)  See the updated fiddle:

**http://jsfiddle.net/freginold/atg8xcyd/1/**

This is the updated HTML code for the top anchor element:

```
<a name="topAnchor" href="#myAnchor" rel="" id="topAnchor" class="anchorLink">Link to the anchor</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with JQuery. As a function it is reusable:

```
function goTo(goToElement) {
        $('body').animate({scrollTop:$(goToElement).offset().top}, 1500);
}
```

In any HTML element just set onclick="goTo('#id_to_goTo')" and it will smooth scroll to the element id you passed in either up or down.